# Ruby gem (module) to organize CLI options and arguments

Tags: ruby, rubygems, command-line-interface

I'm looking for a gem which could help to organize command line (CLI) input options and/or arguments and output to end user as well.

Something like in [Symfony/Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html) (PHP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Commander](https://github.com/commander-rb/commander) is quite good. Also, check out the book [Build Awesome Command Line Applications in Ruby 2](https://pragprog.com/book/dccar2/build-awesome-command-line-applications-in-ruby-2).

Comment: Yeah, it looks good.

Comment: I've found these ones: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/CLI_Option_Parsers

Comment: And this review article: http://www.sitepoint.com/ruby-command-line-interface-gems/